# Which is the user-friendly csv structure to work with d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

An issue of confusion when am working with d3 is the way in which the CSV file should be structured because when I plot the data it's either not working or the chart hasn't been plotted as intended. This usually happens when am dealing with a large dataset and it's usually structured like this:

```
indicator, country, value
population, country-1,5653232
population, country-2,31389
population, country-3,97423
population, country-4, 4565952
.....
rainfall,country-1, 12146
rainfall,country-2, 12146
rainfall,country-3, 12146
rainfall,country-4, 12146
....
CO2 Emission, country-1,56565
CO2 Emission, country-2,2120
CO2 Emission, country-3,6895
CO2 Emission, country-4,53232
```

However most tutorials I have seen usually work with CSV structured like this:

```
country, population,....., rainfall,...., CO2 Emissions
country-1, 132661,....,454151,....,4121212
country-2, 32416,....,98532,....,13262
country-3, 1953,....,65494,....,5465
country-4, 459562323,....,62262,....,5961232
```

So What I would like to know is, which CSV structure should I be using?

Comment: It depends of what you need to render, both formats look usable...